# Why the following js code is not working?

Tags: javascript, window, requestanimationframe

The code

```
var x = {};

x.request = window.requestAnimationFrame;

function step(timestamp) {

    console.log('sth');
}

x.request(step);
```

It returns:

> NS_ERROR_XPC_BAD_OP_ON_WN_PROTO: Illegal operation on WrappedNative
>   prototype object

It should make  x.request working the same as window.requestAnimationFrame.
I need it because I want to make something like:

```
x.request = window.requestAnimationFrame
                ||
            window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame
                ||
            window.mozRequestAnimationFrame;
```

Comment: [An article](http://www.paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/) from Paul Irish with a polyfill

Comment: Yes, but assigning it to the window object was not what I've been looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a problem of *context*. Context is the value of `this` inside the function.

For example:

```
var a = {
    name: 'object a',
    fn: function() {
        return name;
    }
},
    b = {
    name: 'object b'
};

b.fn = a.fn;
console.log(b.fn());
```

Which result will you get? You might think that you'd get `'object a'`, because that's how the function was defined. In fact you will get `object b`, because that is how the function is called. You are providing a *context* for the function call, and that context is the object `b`.

You can see the clear parallel with your code!

```
x.request = window.requestAnimationFrame;
x.request(step);
```

Now, the context for the call is `x`. Clearly `requestAnimationFrame` cares about its context and won't work with the wrong one.

You therefore need to provide the right one. There are two ways of doing this. You can set the context at the time you call the function using [`Function#call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call), or you can set the context earlier using [`Function#bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind):

```
// with call
x.request.call(window, step); // provide the window object as the context

// with bind
x.request = window.requestAnimationFrame.bind(window);
```

(Note, though, that not all browsers support `bind`, so you will need to [provide a shim for those that don't](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind#Compatibility).)

Answer (score 6):

Try

```
x.request.call(window, step);
```

That'll make sure that `this` is `window`.